# QGIS Server limitations?

Tags: qgis, geoserver, mapserver, qgis-server

[QGIS Server](http://docs.qgis.org/html/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_ogc/ogc_server_support.html) seems to be fairly simple to setup and create services, however I'm wondering if there are any limitations with using it opposed to [MapServer](http://mapserver.org/) or [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/Welcome).  My current server configurations is:

**System** - One GIS Server

[image]

**Environment** - GIS, DB Server on same machine

**Users** - 50-100 internal users per day

**Function** - serving data via OpenLayers for data viewing and data extraction

Using QGIS Server are there any obvious limitations or shortcomings with the following:

1. User manual/general help
2. Creating WMS/WFS/WFS-T
3. General Admin. tool/interface of the server for setting roles, security..etc
4. Creating cached WMS tiles
5. Serving out large PostGIS tables (million plus records per table)
6. Updating services

Comment: Can you tell us more about your deployment scenario - environment, number of users, expected load, admin concept? Different tools obviously have different strengths and weaknesses - there is no single best (or even better) tool for all scenarios.

Comment: @BradHards, I updated my question per your comment.

Answer (score 5):

QGIS Server has some limitations but you can add Lizmap on top and get more functionalities.

- The [documentation](http://docs.3liz.com/en/index.html) is good and often updated.
- It handles [users/groups](http://docs.3liz.com/en/lizmap-web-client/administration/users-groups.html).
- Cache management
- Bing, Google, IGN, OSM base layers
- You can easily build html popup for getFeatureInfo calls.
- The [Lizmap plugin](http://docs.3liz.com/en/lizmap-plugin/index.html) is very handy and gives you a nice GUI.
- The [Lizmap web client](http://docs.3liz.com/en/lizmap-web-client/index.html) based on OpenLayers is the QGIS web client equivalent but it is nicer (my opinion) and you can easily modify it using theme. You get WFS controls to make crud operations.
- You can easily [extend the openlayers 2](https://docs.3liz.com/en/publish/advanced_lizmap_config.html#adding-your-own-javascript) frontend binding to multiple events

I didn't test the performance but I never had problems.

**Update 2017-01-17 :** 
If you were not convinced by QGIS Server 2, QGIS Server 3 will be released around July 2017. It will be a complete rewrite. Give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

New functionality has been added into QGIS Server and [as of 2.2](http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/preamble/whats_new.html#qgis-server), QGIS Server can serve out data via WMS(version 1.3.0 and 1.1.1), WFS (version 1.0.0), WFS-T as well as WCS (version 1.0.0) standard.

The rest of the answer is still valid.

---

I won't suggest the use of QGIS server in the production environment, since it has [limited](http://live.osgeo.org/en/overview/qgis_mapserver_overview.html) features.

The reasons are as follows:

- Very limited documentation help.
- No support for users or Groups.
- No inbuilt caching options.
- Slower performance than Geoserver (I don't have any stats or citation on this. I have just seen this in my personal testing)

I would suggest that you use a fully features GIS server like Geoserver in the production environment. You get things like a fully featured Admin Interface, WFS, Caching through GeoWeb Cache, several plugins, an OpenLayers Preview, and so on.

Comment: Please note that there is WFS and WFST support in QGIS Server http://demo.3liz.com/wfst/wfs-transaction-polygon.html

Comment: @underdark I was not aware of this patch. Has it been integrated in the trunk by default?

Comment: I think so: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/5094 but haven't tried it yet.

Comment: I can agree on the above mentioned reasons. Especially the performance is surprisingly slow.

Comment: No support for users or Groups, is completely misleading. There is plenty of support, comunitywise or commercial: https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/support.html