# GIS Server - evaluation architecture

Tags: geoserver, wms, mapserver

Building from my previous questions:

[QGIS Server limitations?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/56738/qgis-server-limitations#comment75112_56738)

I want to evaluate performance of both MapServer and GeoServer.  Can both servers exist on the same machine (each serving out WMS) or should I set them up on separate servers?

Answer (score 4):

You can check out this site with detailed comparison of Mapserver vs. Geoserver
http://www.esdmdata.co.uk/mapserver-and-geoserver-and-tilecache-comparison-serving-ordnance-survey-raster-maps

Comment: Wonderful Link!

Answer (score 3):

You can install both of them on the same system; You just need to make sure that they use different ports.

You had mentioned that you have a Windows Server. If you use [MS4W](http://www.maptools.org/ms4w/) for Mapserver, it uses port 80 by default. And if you use the GeoServer [Windows Installer](http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/Stable), it will use port 8080 by default.

So the defaults should work just fine, as long as you don't have something else running on these ports.