# What should I start with Web GIS MapServer?

Tags: postgis, openlayers, c#, mapserver, php

I'm not native English Speaker and I'm a graduated student who wants to have a masters degree in software engineering.  I have a thesis relative with "Build a Web GIS for air pollution in Viet Nam's capital city". But I've never any experiences with GIS. I've searched some Google, this shows me that I should use MapServer, OpenLayers and PostGIS SQL.

Now, I think user will query from web browser and based in OpenLayers function JavaScript, It'll transfer data to MapServer (I think can use PHP MapScript here to handle query), after that MapServer can get data from PostGIS SQL if it needs (after all, MapServer will return a image that fits all user's query).

Please, correct me if I'm wrong or teach me some knowledge.

Comment: I'm also based in Hanoi, Vietnam, and am also doing a degree, but this time a GIS masters thesis (just starting). I would PM if I could - but I don't think I have that privilege yet. If you want to drop me a line do it on simplest2rememeber a t gmail d o t com and we can talk about GIS, the universe and everything.
dave

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your question is subjective (a matter of opinion) so it might be voted down (-1). Since your new to this site, I will go ahead and answer -- mapserver, open layers and postgis sql would be a very good combination for an open source solution. Geoserver is also an option instead of mapserver -- it is java based. There are also other javascript libraries such as leaflet that people often use.

You will likely need a GIS data viewer, editor and tools to prepare your data. QGIS works well with postgis sql and is free, opensource. You can also issue direct spatial sql queries to postgis.

Check out these questions
[GIS Server - evaluation architecture](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/56987/gis-server-evaluation-architecture)
[How do various JavaScript mapping libraries compare?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8032/comparison-of-javascript-mapping-libraries)

Good luck!

Note: I was just looking at tags for geoserver and mapserver. On this site, 938 questions have been tagged with geoserver versus 220 questions with mapserver.

Comment: Really thanks for your information. I just new so thanks for your patient.