# Render specific vector data from database with OpenLayers

Tags: postgis, geoserver, openlayers, json

I want to render some data on a map. They are stored as points in my database (PostGIS), each one is associated with a name. I want to render points with the same place name in the same colour.

However, I don't want to put the name of the places directly in my .xml style file. (Too many places)

Do you know how can I do ?

Maybe an idea is to try to return JSON data in OpenLayers js, but I don't know how I can get it. Does GeoServer enable to return JSON to OpenLayers?

Comment: yes, you are. You should start reading [this](http://macwright.org/2012/05/15/how-web-maps-work.html), [this](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/geog585/l1_p6.html), [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_mapping) and [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59629/what-should-i-start-with-webgis-mapserver)

Answer (score 1):

If you are serving your data with Geoserver, let me suggest that you serve the data as a WMS service.

You can style the data with SLD, and have them labeled, like shown in this article: [Labeling](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld-reference/labeling.html)